# Probability of wearing a hat

Tags: probability, markov-chains

A man has n hats that he keeps in two drawers. Every morning, he flips a (fair) coin to choose a drawer at random to take a hat from, if there is one. Every night, he flips a coin to choose which drawer to put the hat back into, if he wore one. What is the fraction of days he does not wear a hat?

I'm quite stuck on how to get going... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if he doesn't wear a hat, what does he do with the nightly coin flip?

Comment: Hint: You have $n+1$ states, counting the number of hats in each drawer.

Comment: doesn't the starting state matter?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: this is a Markov Chain with a unique stationary distribution, so presumably that is the distribution intended to be used

Comment: @Henry;; its just that a random walk centers around its origin

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: A drunkard staggering down a corridor may spend as much time near the walls as he does near the centre and his final position in the corridor may not be significantly affected by his starting position.

Comment: @Henry; which contrevenes the law of averages

Comment: Following @Henry's lead (and ignoring the snark), I suggest you try it with $n=3$ hats and four states $0,1,2,3$ denoting the number of hats in the left drawer in the morning. Write the probabilities in the $4×4$ one-step transition matrix and find its stationary distribution. With luck you'll see a generalizable pattern. States 0 and 3 could lead to going hatless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a simple Markov chain on $n+1$ states (enumerated by the number of hats in the first drawer). Simple calculation shows that in steady state all states are equiprobable - hence they have probability $\frac 1 {n+1}$. A man doesn't wear a hat only in states $0$ and $n$ and in those states probability of non wearing a hat is $\frac 1 2$. Hence he doesn't wear a hat on $\frac 1 {n+1}$ fraction of days.

Answer (score 1):

Common sense answer:  On a day he wore a hat, he flips a coin to decide which drawer to put it in.  He has a fifty fifty chance of putting it in the same drawer as the other hat and a fifty fifty chance of putting it in the other drawer.  So on half the days the hats are in the same drawer and on half the days they are in different drawers.  On the days they are in different drawers, he will always wear a hat.  On half of the days where they are in the same drawer he will wear a hat and on half of those days he will not.  So he will wear a hat one-quarter of the days.

AND THE COMMON SENSE ANSWER IS WRONG.  Even if n = 2.

Comment: That deals with $n=2$ but it might be greater

Comment: But on the days he wears no hat the drawers are unchanged.  This messes up the count.

Comment: This common sense approach is not correct.  If we let $p_i$ denote the probability that the first drawer contains $i$ hats then, in equilibrium, we must have $p_0=\frac 34 p_0+ \frac 14 p_1$, $p_2=\frac 34 p_2+ \frac 14 p_1$,$p_1=\frac 14 p_0+ \frac 12 p_1+\frac 14 p_2$.  Easy to see that equilibrium has $p_i=\frac 13\;\forall i$.

Comment: D'oh, d'oh, d'oh!  D'OH!!!!!! For some reason I can not possibly explain or justify I simply read it as the man had 2 hats.  Of course, he doesn't and of course my answer won't work if n doesn't equal 2.

Comment: And, further, dammit.  lulu, you are right.  Even if n=2 my common sense answer is wrong.  So, um, why the heck is my wrong answer being upvoted?